# Gridview with buttonfield delete & Linq to SQL DAL

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, buttonfield

I'm trying implement a simple `Button` field in the `GridView`.

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
```

I have a three-tier application that I'll combine into one function for this example:

```
protected void GV1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        var deletion = (HRA_internalLesion) GV1.SelectedRow.DataItem;
        DataContext conn = new DataContext();

        conn.HRA_internalLesions.DeleteOnSubmit(deletion); 
        conn.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

I'm sure the `var deletion` line is not returning the Linq to SQL object I want.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataItem` property isn't available after the control has been rendered initially. You'll have to re-create the data object from your fields on the page if you want to do this.

**Edit:**

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx):

> The DataItem property is only available during and after the RowDataBound event of a GridView control.

I'm not sure why it says "and after" -- this is confusing language to me -- but nonetheless, there's documented evidence.